# How can I get a border to work correctly html

Tags: html, css, border, padding

So i'm butting a border around a div like so

```css
#menu{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 100px 0px 0px 20px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

But the border ignores the padding or something as can be seen on the image
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmov8.jpg)

Comment: The padding is top 100px and left 20px. That looks correct to me. What are you expecting?

Comment: the shorthand property  working on clockwise `padding: top right bottom left`

Comment: The padding is correct but it's the border that isn't where i want it to be if you look at the image.

Comment: the same concept for padding apply on margin

Comment: I can look at the image as long as I want. With the information you provided the border is right there where it should be. The problem is you didn‘t tell us what you expect where/how the border should be. From the information you provided I can say it looks all good

Answer (score 1):

According to **CSS Box Model** Border is right in between margin and padding. 
[CSS Box Model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

I am not sure exactly how do you want your design to be but, you can try that shorthand property you used in padding, in margin, Like this:

```
#menu{
  margin: 100px 0px 0px 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px ;
}
```

I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try these values:

```
#menu{
margin: 0px;
padding: 100px 0px 0px 20px;
//padding: top right bottom left
float: left;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 10px ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the padding has four values:

```
padding:10px 5px 15px 20px;
```

This means:

```
 - top padding is 10px 
 - right padding is 5px 
 - bottom padding is 15px 
 - left padding is 20px
```

And similar is for border-radius:

```
border-radius: 15px 50px 30px 5px;
```

(first value applies to top-left corner, second value applies to top-right corner,third value applies to bottom-right corner, and fourth value applies to bottom-left corner)

So you can try this:

```
#menu {
  margin: 0px;    
  padding: 100px 0px 0px 20px;    
  float: left;   
  border: 1px solid black;  
  border-radius: 10px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example is below. for further clarifications visit [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

```
<p class="round3">Roundest border</p>

p.round3 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is working for me

```
#menu p{
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 50px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        width: 300px;
    }

<div id="menu">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```